# Passbook Pass does not load Localization

Tags: localization, passbook

I made a Passbook pass for the hostel I work at. However, I didn't get the Pass to load the localization file. In the `pass.json` file I have this code:

```
"primaryFields" : [
  {
    "key" : "offer",
    "label" : "offer_night",
    "value" : "offer_free"
  }
]
```

then I the `en.lproj/pass.strings` I have the following:

```
"offer_night" = "1 night";
"offer_free" = "FREE";
```

Now, when I load the pass on my phone, I only get the offer_night and offer_free and not 1 night and FREE.

Do I need to configure something that I haven't thought of so far?

EDIT: I am using the Apple signpass script. When I unzip the pass, the lproj folders are there. In the manifest the files are listed but the path is wrong (see my comment below).

Comment: are you including the files in the manifest? Could you provide your pkpass file?

Comment: Well, I'm using the signpass script from Apple. The files are included in the manifest. However, the path is wrong: "en.lproj\/pass.strings" How and where can I fix this?

Comment: @ChristianSeiler, I have a similar issue, were you able to fix the problem?